# bare bones x11 how to draw a truetype or other antialiased font?

Tags: fonts, x11

How to draw a text using barebones X11 connection over a socket?

I connect to x11 server via socket and handle the protocol manually. I do not use Xlib or XCB, leave alone Qt, GTK or even Freetype. I have one unresolved issue, I cannot draw fonts other than ancient bitmap fonts. I would like to draw something like FreeSans or other Unicode enabled fonts with LCD sub-pixel rendering, but using only built-in x11 functionality. Probably using some x11-extension. But which one? What function to use? How to select a font, locally or on server? Can X11 render the font for me using the provided style information, including color, background color, font name, size and decoration?

Comment: Seeing as you're reinventing the wheel, why not use a blunt rock? :-) Try using WireShark to capture the X11 messages sent/received by a "hello, world!" style app in some toolkit that *does* let you easily use UniCode fonts with sub-pixel rendering. (Ask a silly question, get a silly suggestion)

Comment: but many apps will render font client-side, using freetype or similar lib, I would love to decode packets if I knew the app that definetly is doing what I am looking for, can you suggest such an app?

Comment: write one yourself in a (Unicode, Sub-pixel aware -supporting) toolkit. Then capture traffic from it. If you can't/won't do that, then you have no business writing an app making use of bare X11 protocol.

Comment: @David-SkyMesh, I can do that, but all I will capture is bitmaps prepared by freetype on client side sent to server. I want to use server-side text rendering.

Comment: So use a toolkit that allows you to do that. If you can't find one that fits your criteria, you'd have to ask yourself the question.. "why?".

Comment: You have to re-implement FreeType. Good luck.

Comment: Server-side text rendering only has simple monochrome font support - all antialiasing, LCD sub-pixel rendering, etc. is only implemented on the client side, with libraries like Xft & freetype: http://www.x.org/wiki/guide/fonts/

Comment: @alanc, Xft that you mention _is_ server side version of freetype.

Comment: @exebook, no, Xft uses freetype on the client side to render text and uses either the Render extension to upload glyphs or core X11 PutImage requests to upload the entire text image.

Comment: @alanc, are you sure? after I read the whole introduction paper I was quite sure about the opposite. doh

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, X does not render fonts for you, but it can render sequences of anti-aliased pixmap "Glyphs". If you only want to use core X protocol, you'll have to render everything client-side (most libraries do this anyway, usually with cairo library).

What I suggest to try: 1) pre-render all glyphs for your font locally using FreeType; 2) Upload fonts with CreateGlyphSet Xrender request; 3) Draw you string with CompositeGlyphs8/16/32 request. Read section 12 - "Glyph Rendering" of XRender [documentation](http://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.6/doc/renderproto/renderproto.txt). Each glyph has its own offset value, however there is no way to define kerning pairs.

You'll have to handle other complexities as well (right-to left, vertical, etc). It's a very complex task to do 100% correct, but sans edge cases is doable for sure and a good educational project.

You can look at example of raw socket + xrender communication in my javascript x client library: https://github.com/sidorares/node-x11

Comment: great job binding x11 to node. Have you been thinking about implementing Xft extension (Server-side freetype)? http://keithp.com/~keithp/talks/xtc2001/paper/ I have seen protocol PDF somewhere as well.

Comment: I'm thinking about 'server side javascript' extension so that you can upload scripts to X11. Not so sure about freetype extension - you can achieve everything it does with XRender and local glyph generation

Comment: I'd like to add fonts functionality to node-x11 (or on top of it - to https://github.com/sidorares/ntk) but I'll probably have API similar to web fonts